# android: textView can't setText time from TimePicker

Tags: android, timepicker

I have button and textView. When i clicked the button, timePicker will show up. But, when i finish set a hour and minute and will display it in TextView, it unfortunately stop

my codes :

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute, true);
    }
    return null;
}
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = 
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() { 
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,int selectedMinute) {

        hour = selectedHour;
        minute = selectedMinute;

        //error here================= What's Wrong?
        tvDisplayTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":")
       .append(pad(minute)));
        }}; 
       // ===============================
private static String pad(int c) {
    if (c >= 10)
       return String.valueOf(c);
    else
       return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
}
}
```

Why when  i try to set hour and minute from TimePicker and show it in TextView always error??

Please help...

Log :

`07-27 18:14:24.661: E/SpannableStringBuilder(7324): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-27 18:14:24.661: E/SpannableStringBuilder(7324): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-27 18:14:30.901: D/AndroidRuntime(7324): Shutting down VM
07-27 18:14:30.901: W/dalvikvm(7324): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42034438)
07-27 18:14:30.911: E/AndroidRuntime(7324): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 18:14:30.911: E/AndroidRuntime(7324): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 18:14:30.911: E/AndroidRuntime(7324):     at com.example.b_timepicker.MainActivity$1.onTimeSet(MainActivity.java:98)
07-27 18:14:30.911: E/AndroidRuntime(7324):     at android.app.TimePickerDialog.tryNotifyTimeSet(TimePickerDialog.java:201)
07-27 18:14:30.911: E/AndroidRuntime(7324):     at android.app.TimePickerDialog.onClick(TimePickerDialog.java:165)
07-27 18:14:30.911: E/AndroidRuntime(7324):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
07-27 18:14:30.911: E/AndroidRuntime(7324):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 18:14:30.911: E/AndroidRuntime(7324):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-27 18:14:30.911: E/AndroidRuntime(7324):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
07-27 18:14:30.911: E/AndroidRuntime(7324):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 18:14:30.911: E/AndroidRuntime(7324):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-27 18:14:30.911: E/AndroidRuntime(7324):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
07-27 18:14:30.911: E/AndroidRuntime(7324):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
07-27 18:14:30.911: E/AndroidRuntime(7324):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: Unfortunately stopped, i want to sharred all my code, but stackoverflow say it too much

Comment: Show your Logcat, please.

Comment: @HuyTran: ok, i will show it

Comment: Which is line 98 of `MainActivity`?

Comment: Line 98 - `tvDisplayTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":")
       .append(pad(minute)));
        }};`

Comment: @virho Where are you declaring your tvDisplayTime View?

Comment: @Joao: in MainActivity,

Comment: thanks for your all response, it clear now. thank you especially for you joao, i understand now ..

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you are declaring your `tvDisplayTime` `TextView` correctly, so it is not null when you call `setText()`. Also make sure that `tvDisplayTime` is defined on the right layout.